# why physics is not working with SKShapes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skshapenode

I am trying to detect the collision between the circle called player and the balls called enemyCircle but nothing happen

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        if let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node as? SKShapeNode, let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node as? SKShapeNode {
            if nodeA.fillColor != nodeB.fillColor {
                print("not same color")
            }else {
                print("same color")
            }
        }

    }

    private func drawPlayer(radius: CGFloat) {
        player = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        player.physicsBody?.pinned = true
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyType.player.rawValue
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bodyType.enemy.rawValue
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = bodyType.enemy.rawValue
        player.strokeColor = SKColor.purple
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        player.glowWidth = 2.0
        world.addChild(player)
    }

    private func drawEnemy(radius: CGFloat, color: SKColor) {
        let enemyCircle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius)
        enemyCircle.fillColor = color
        enemyCircle.glowWidth = 0.5
        enemyCircle.strokeColor = color
        enemyCircle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: radius)
        enemyCircle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        enemyCircle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        enemyCircle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = bodyType.player.rawValue
        enemyCircle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = bodyType.enemy.rawValue
        let nextEnemyPosition = determineNextEnemyPosition()
        let enemyPosition = spawnAtRandomPosition(edge: nextEnemyPosition)
        enemyCircle.position = enemyPosition
        world.addChild(enemyCircle)
        numberOfEnemies += 1
        enemyCircle.name = String(numberOfEnemies)
        enemy.append(enemyCircle)
        runToCenter(enemy: enemyCircle)
    }

enum bodyType: UInt32 {
        case enemy = 1
        case player = 2
    }
```

and this

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate
```

and i put this in didMove func

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

can someone explain me the issues here

Note:: I made both not dynamic as I don't want anyone to move the other or change it, just be notified when it touches so I stop the game

Comment: Because both of your physics bodies have `isDynamic` property set to false. At least one body has to be dynamic.

Comment: can't i just check the position of enemy balls each frame ? but the problem is that the player is a circle so how i check it ? i can't just say player.position == enemy.position

Comment: You can, contact detection can be done by checking for intersection between nodes, but isnt a physics engine a convenient way to go?

Comment: you mean using contact delegate ?

Comment: No. I meant using update: method. You mentioned checking positions of nodes that intersect.

Comment: i made it dynamic and it worked with contact delegate thank you a lot :D

Comment: Okay we made a bit of a confusion. When I said to set isDynamic to true, then yes, you do that in didBegin(contact:) which is executed when contact is detected by physics engine. When I said you can check the intersection between two nodes by checking the intersection of their frames, then I meant you should use update: method (which is executed 60 per seconds). In latter case, if body us circular, it is likely that checking intersection could be problematic, so using physics engine is the way to go.